# Scanner input through break-line

Tags: java, input

Is it possible to catch a break-line as an "input-confirmation"?

The idea is that you skip an input, if it should not be used. Or is there an already existing java method for that problem?

Edit code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class probe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input:");

        boolean input = false;

        if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            input=true;
        }else if(!(scanner.hasNextLine())){
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        System.out.println(input);  
    }
}
```

So `.hasNextLine()` is obviously not the right method to solve my problem, I just implemented it like that, because I think it is getting clearer.
But I think I'm already on the wrong way.
One Solution which come to my mind is, that to compare the char-value of an break-line to the inputed char.
I'm Sorry if I can't explain my problem more properly :(

Comment: This sounds like an IDE-related problem, like in Eclipse only.

Comment: Can you give example of what you are trying to achieve to make your question clearer?

Comment: So if the user doesn't want to enter something, he can skip the input by pressing *Return*? Then get that input using `String answer = scanner.nextLine();` and then check if it is empty: `if (answer.isEmpty()) { ... input skipped ... }`.

Comment: Well, that was pretty obvious though -.- ... Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom already pointed out this should be the code snippet you're looking for:

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line.isEmpty() ? "Nothing to print out" : "Your input was: " + line);
}
```